# how to create generic function which will return value of any level of pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, generic-programming

I want a function which will return value of the **pointer**, regardless what level of **pointer** it is.
Like it could be single OR double pointer OR Triple pointer OR more, but that function should return the value.

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T func(T arg){
      // what to do here or there is some other way to do this?????
}

int main() {
    int *p, **pp, ***ppp;
    p = new int(5);
    pp = &p;
    ppp = &pp;

    cout << func(p);    // should print 5
    cout << func(pp);   // should print 5
    cout << func(ppp);  // should print 5
    return 0;
}
```

So, now I want to pass this p, pp, ppp in only one function and it should print or return the value '5'.

Comment: Impossible. But why do you think you need that?

Comment: @Amit i just kind of thought like that while return from office to my room :D

Comment: A triple pointer *is* a double pointer *and* a single pointer as well.  In fact, considering all pointers to be single pointers provides a better mental model.  That the target of a pointer is also a pointer is of very little significance in a generic sense, for pointer types are perfectly valid types in their own right.

Comment: @Amit: Not quite as impossible as you thought :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just have one overload that takes any pointer and calls itself dereferenced, and one overload that takes anything:

```
template <class T>
T func(T arg) {
    return arg;
}

template <class T>
auto func(T* arg){
    return func(*arg);
}
```

This is even possible without C++11, just have to write a type trait to do all the dereferencing too:

```
template <class T>
struct value_type { typedef T type; };

template <class T>
struct value_type<T*> : value_type<T> { };

template <class T>
T func(T arg) {
    return arg;
}

template <class T>
typename value_type<T>::type func(T* arg){
    return func(*arg);
}
```

Comment: could you plz add some explanation about second method..
would be very helpful.